# libphonenumber on iOS usage example

Tags: ios, libphonenumber

I'm trying to use libphonenumber on iOS. I'm using [Matt Connolly's libphonenumber-ios](https://github.com/mattconnolly/libphonenumber-ios) from GitHub and I've build boost framework and it's all fine.

Now I can't figure out how to actually use it after I drag libphonenumber.a inside my Xcode project! Any simple usage example along with what headers need to be imported would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about to use this ?

full port google libphonenumber

https://github.com/iziz/libPhoneNumber-iOS

Comment: I ended up having to implement what I needed on my own. I haven't tried the port on your answer but it looks like what I needed, so I'm going to accept your answer. Thanks.

Comment: It seems this does not include the 'AsYouTypeFormatter', which was my main (but not only) reason for trying the Google library.  I ended up writing a small wrapper (consisting of a small piece of JavaScript) around the ~200kB JavaScript I built using the supplied instructions and other insights; it was not easy to do. I run it in a hidden `UIWebView` and it all (including AsYouTypeFormatter) works great and very fast.